# Android eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to create buttons at run time, which I did. The problem is they all overlap each other. I want to change the position and nothing is working!

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    b.setText(""+ i);      
    b.setId(100+i);
    b.setWidth(50);
    b.setHeight(40);

    p1.this.addContentView(b, p);              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout and [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html).Set params's values and add it like `linearLayout.addView(button, params)` that.